# Python sqlite3 select from statement returns empty list when fetched

Tags: python, sqlite, pygtk

I'm writing a program in pygtk with sqlite as database backend, I have successfully created the database with one table and six columns using:

```
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabl (
                 Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, Condition TEXT, Medicine TEXT, 
                 Age TEXT, Date DATE)''')
```

I insert values into it using:

```
    def save(Name, Age, Condition, Medicine):
       T = [(Name).title(),(Age).title(),(Condition).title(),(Medicine).title()]
       conn = sqlite3.connect('patients.db')
       cur = conn.cursor()
       conn.text_factory = str
       cur.execute('INSERT INTO tabl (Name,Condition,Medicine, Age,Date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,date("now"))',(T))
```

Values are supplied by the GUI.

Now I have a combobox in the search dialog that I'll use to specify searching for which type (name, age, date, or condition), so I used the index of the selected item for that, that's the main module:

```
    def find(self,widget):
            index = self.comboBy.get_active()
            nameU = self.entryFor.get_text()
            name = nameU.title()
            names = database.findItem(name,index)
```

and here's the database.FindItem:

```
    namen = name.title()
    if index == 0:
            print index
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tabl WHERE Name=?",[namen])
    elif index == 1:
            print index
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tabl WHERE Age=?",[namen])
    elif index == 2:
            print index
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tabl WHERE Date=?",[namen])
    else:
            print index
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tabl WHERE Condition=?",[namen])
    list = cur.fetchall()
    print list
    return list
```

that works only when supplying the name, it prints the index 0 and gets the right list,
but when trying with some other column such as condition, it returns an empty list [], although it print the right index and sees the right column, I'm confused, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*EDIT: redacted incorrect information about the use of `cursor.execute()`.*

Have you tried running your SQL query on the database directly (without using Python?) Your problem may be the query, or that there really is no data matching your query.

SQLiteMan is a good tool for direct manipulation of SQLite databases.

---

You can also condense your if...else block down to a single statement using a `dict`. (This is the pythonic way to implement a switch...case statement as found in other languages.)

```
queries = { 0: "SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE Name=?",
            1: "SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE Age=?",
            2: "SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE Date=?",
            3: "SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE Condition=?" }
results = cur.execute ( queries[index], [namen] )
```

Or even more compactly:

```
match_by = {0: 'Name', 1: 'Age', 2: 'Date', 3: 'Condition'}
query = "SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE %s=?" % match_by[index]
results = cur.execute(query,[namen])
```

Or even *more* compact, you can inline the dictionary:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE %s=?" % {0: 'Name', 1: 'Age', 2: 'Date', 3: 'Condition'}[index]
results = cur.execute(query,[namen])
```

Or the ultimately compact one-liner

```
results = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE %s=?" % {0: 'Name', 1: 'Age', 2: 'Date', 3: 'Condition'}[index] ,[namen])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sqliteman was so helpful, the mistake was in the T list, it shuffled Age column with Condition column, problem solved :).